# how to use OnItemLongClickListener without setOnItemLongClickListener in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use OnItemLongClickListener for a listView on Android. This code works fine when added to onCreate method.

```
mContactList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("MyApp", "get onItem Click position= " + position);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

However when I try to implement OnItemLongClickListener interface and use this method in the class:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)   {
    Log.e("MyApp", "get onItem Click position= " + position);
    return false;
}
```

nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your full code how you are implementing the Listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have to set an setOnItemLongClickListener.
If you extract the onClick listener to another class than you have to set this OnItemLongClickListener to the listview.

e.g.

```
mContactList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new MyClassOnLogItemClickListener());
```

or if you are in the same class register it with `this`.

Comment: Thank you. That what I was missing.

Answer (score 5):

Did you register your object as listener, eg. `setOnItemLongClickListener(this)`?